# Ng-if to judge multiple numbers

Tags: angular, typescript

I have lots of questionnaire, and now I want to use *ngIf to filter which not to appear in some div.

the stupid way now I use is to sign individually

```
<div *ngIf = "questionNo!= '00' && questionNo!= '04' && questionNo != '21'">
...</div>
```

and I think there is better way like *ngIf= "questionNo != [00.01,02....]"
but I try but in vain.

so I need your help~ thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `&&` or `||` or:

`*ngIf= "[00,01,02].includes(questionNo)"`

`*ngIf= "![00,01,02].includes(questionNo)"`

Answer (score 1):

I would move that condition to component code into `shouldShowSomething():bool` as it is much clearer and maintainable + can take arguments for eventual parametrization.

Comment: Valid approach, however, I would like to mention that if the component ChangeDetection strategy is Default, such an approach will cause performance hog.

Comment: What if we bind that to property instead of method? followup -> will getter method be hogging as well ?

Comment: Getter wouldn't be hogging, but you can't have getter with parameters. You can't bind method to a property, how would that work?